Overriding SCSS Stylesheet
I have a selector that was kept overriding by another stylesheet.
Things I did and didn't work:

Check if the selector was correctly nested
Move my SCSS file to the end of app.scss to make it with highest importance.

editorial/scss/_post-box.scss code snippet:
@import "common/scss/post-box";

app.scss file:
// Pages
@import "post-box";
@import "common/scss/page/about";
@import "common/scss/page/subscription";

// Postbox
@import "editorial/scss/post-box";

I cannot add ID/extra class to the selector as I was asked to use the same template for different SCSS file.
Also, I wasn't allowed to use !important.
Any pointers will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot!
Need my selector in editorial/scss/post-box.scss stylesheet to override common/scss/post-box.scss stylesheet.

You may want to look at specificity

@Gerard Thanks a lot! I added one of the classes from the body tag and it works now!

And more importantly, you learned something new today.
